# Examples of three prefixes in one word

Tags: prefixes

Do you know words which consist of three prefixes (in one word)? It's difficult to find such examples, but I've read that there are such words in English.

Comment: You got yourself a good research project right there. Let us know what you find.

Comment: Why would you want to know such a thing? Sounds like trainspotting to me. Hardly a question of linguistic interest.

Answer (score 1):

I found a few examples of words with two productive prefixes added to a verb composed of a Latinate prefix and another bound Latinate morpheme. Latinate prefixes are normally considered a type of prefix in English morphology.

[unreconstructed](http://www.onelook.com/?w=unreconstructed&ls=a&loc=home_ac_unrecog):

> not reconciled to some political, economic, or social change - *an unreconstructed rebel*; also :  holding stubbornly to a particular belief, view, place, or style - *an unreconstructed hard-liner*

([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unreconstructed))

> Not reconciled or converted to the current political theory or movement.
>   *‘an unreconstructed elitist’*

([Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/unreconstructed))

> 1. Not reconciled to social, political, or economic change; maintaining outdated attitudes, beliefs, and practices.
> 2. Not reconciled to the outcome of the American Civil War.

([American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=unreconstructed))

un<sup>1</sup>-([re<sup>2</sup>-(con<sup>3</sup>-struct)]-ed):

1. negative prefix *un-*, attaches to adjectives, productive in modern English, native and inherited from Proto-Indo-European negative prefix **n̥-*.
2. repetitive prefix *re-*, attaches to verbs, productive in modern English, borrowed from French *re-/ré-* and its ancestor Latin *re-.*
3. Latin prepositional prefix *con-,* etymologically the same as the Latin independent preposition *cum*; borrowed and not really productive in this form in modern English, but the prefix *co-,* which was used in Latin as an allomorph of *con-* before a vowel or the letter *h,* is somewhat productive in modern English. There is some phonological evidence for *con-*'s status as a prefix in the current morpho-phonological system of English; see Greg Lee's answer to *[The pronunciation of words which begins 'con' and 'com'](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/227252/77227).* Also, it seems likely that most English speakers would be able to recognize a boundary between "con" and "struct" in this word because each of these sequences occurs independently of the other in many other common Latinate words, such as ***con***front, **con**duction and *de**struct**ion, **struct**ure.*

Other similar examples

- *unrepresentative,* un-([re-(pre-sent)]-ative), if you allow the verb "present" to be analyzed as containing a prefix "pre-".
- *unreproducible,* un-([re-(pro-duc)]-ible), if you allow the verb "produce" to be analyzed as containing a prefix "pro-".

I also found the word "unreinforced", which could be considered to be built by adding affixes to the free morpheme "force": un-([re-(i/*e*n-[forc*e*])]-ed). As you can see, there are some spelling adjustments in the course of the derivation: the verb "enforce" is spelled with an "e" rather than an "i", but variation between "en-" and "in-" is common in spelling and doesn't necessarily signify a true morphological distinction.